# RegExp inside ng-class raise error

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

Why I have an error when I put Regexp inside ng-class?

```
<a ng-class="{red:isActive(/test/)}"></a>

$scope.isActive = function(regexp){return true}
```

with string or num I havent error..

Answer (score 1):

regexp are not part of angular valid exressions, angular expressions look like javascript expressions but they are not the same
if you need to validate test pass it as a string then build the regexp inside the function using the string and the RegExp object

```
var str="test";
var strReg=new RegExp(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
<a ng-class="{true:'red', false:'other'}[isActive('/test/')]}"></a>

$scope.isActive = function(regexp){return true}
```

I created a plunker with an example http://plnkr.co/edit/DBqtDObgEUaWCFMHRYtb